# Unable to install logtash contrib plugins?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, installation, logstash, riemann

I want to use logstash contrib plugin riemann in my config file. On running logstash error comes:

```
 An unexpected error occurred. This is probably a bug.   |
| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |
|                                                         |
| * chat: #logstash IRC channel on freenode irc.          |
|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |
| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |
| * bug system: https://logstash.jira.com/                |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
The error reported is: 
  Couldn't find any output plugin named 'riemann'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the riemann output plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/outputs/riemann
```

I have a folder inside which both the logstash and its contrib tar are present and extracted.
I am using `logstash 1.4.1` and `logstash-contrib-1.4.1`.

I tried the manual installation for contrib too by :

```
./bin/plugin install contrib
```

but nothing appears on the console on running the command.

Any help?

**EDIT**

On ls the following is my directory structure:

```
ls

    elasticsearch-1.1.1         kibana-3.1.0.tar.gz  logstash-1.4.1.tar.gz   logstash-contrib-1.4.1.tar.gz
    elasticsearch-1.1.1.tar.gz  logstash-1.4.1       logstash-contrib-1.4.1  riemann-0.2.5.tar.bz2
```

Thus I have untarred contrib in the same directory as logstash. Any IDEA??

Answer (score 1):

You shall extract `logstash-contrib-1.4.1.tar.gz` inside `logstash-1.4.1` directory with commands:

```
cd logstash-1.4.1
tar zxvf logstash-contrib-1.4.1.tar.gz --strip 1
```

Then check `lib/logstash/outputs/riemann.rb` is under `logstash-1.4.1`.